# How to print day of the given date?

Tags: java

I'm trying to print a day of the given date. How can I do that?

```
String date = "2015.05.12";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
Date bornDate =  format.parse(date);
System.out.println(bornDate.getDay());//this prints "2" instead of "12"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bornDate.getDate()` to get day. You shall use calendar class as methods on date are deprecated.